# Is there a difference between using equal and IN for a query with a single ID?

Tags: cassandra

I'm wondering if there is any mechanical difference to writing a CQL query to fetch data based on a specific field using '=' or IN keyword. The queries would look like this:
`... WHERE id = "foo"` vs `... WHERE id IN ["foo"]`

I'm currently trying to improve the performance of my queries by bypassing the coordinator node directly by making prepared statements with a token aware policy. I read that for multi-get queries using 'IN' keyword for multiple fields will route through a coordinator node, so I would like to bypass this to improve performance, and I am not sure if that would work if I used 'IN' with a single id. I would also like confirmation that sending 20 queries with one ID would be more performant than sending 1 query with 20 IDs.

Additionally, would this approach with sending a single ID scale the same as we increase the number of nodes in Cassandra? If we have a very large Cassandra, say 90 nodes, but the client only knows three nodes, would this mean we would still go through a coordinator node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple questions here in your ask above.

There is NO parser used in the DataStax drivers for Apache Cassandra® to parse CQL statements, so the optimization you described in the above question cannot be done on the client side. So, if you have just 1 value, it is always better to use it with `=` operator.

Also, it is not a good idea to pile up the query with the `IN` values. If it is just 1 or 2, then it is okay or else, the coordinator node has to wait for all replicas nodes to fetch the data for the values within the `IN` clause to respond to the client back. Instead, the recommended practice here is to [levarage the async queries](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dev-app-drivers/docs/best-practices.html). [Here](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/java-cassandra-driver-from3x-to4x/blob/master/example-4x/src/main/java/com/datastax/samples/SampleCode4x_CRUD_06_Async.java) is an example repo that showcases how to leverage async programming with Java Driver.

For your 3rd question, it will always scale irrespective of the number of nodes in the Cassandra cluster. Also, as soon as the client does its initial handshake, it will anyways know the entire topology of the cluster and your assumption of it will only know 3 nodes as part of the 90-node cluster is incorrect understanding here.

p/s in future, it will be better if you could post multiple questions seperately for better organization.